# Java servets request.getMethod() not working

Tags: java, servlet-3.0, get-method

Hello I am trying to create a simple servlet as follows

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;    
import javax.servlet.http.*;
public class Form extends HttpServlet
{
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException,IOException
    {
     res.setContentType("text/html");
     PrintWriter p=res.getWriter();
     p.println("<html><head></head><body bgcolor=\"red\">The request came from"+req.getMethod()+"</body></html>");
    }

}
```

The req.getMethod() should return POST but is giving me a null value.

I am taking the request from an html file coded as follows.

```
   <html>

   <body>

   <form action="http://localhost:8080/Form" method="GET">

   First Name: <input type="text" name="name"/>

  <br>

   <input type="submit" value="Submit form "/>

  </form>

  </body>

  </html>
```

here is the web.xml file. Should I make any changes here.

```
 <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"  
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee                    
  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"   
  version="3.0"   metadata-complete="true">

    <display-name>Welcome to Tomcat</display-name>
    <description>
     Welcome to Tomcat
    </description>

    <servlet>
     <servlet-name>Form</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>Form</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>Form</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/Form</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    </web-app>
```

Comment: what is the problem ? what is you expected output?

Comment: You probably want to use `req.getParameter("name")` instead of `req.getMethod()`

Comment: what error or output you are seeing?

Comment: are you getting any error.please post your web.xml

Comment: I am not getting error. I am expecting GET method while all I am getting is null

Comment: Please post your web.xml file, as the following link "http://localhost:8080/Form" looks incomplete. It should be like this "http://localhost:8080// {application name}/Form".

Comment: I am just learning servelets. So I am putting everything inside my servlets

Answer (score 0):

You can write this annotation to attach your servlet to your form:

```
@WebServlet("/Form")
public class Form extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException { ... }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException { ... }
}
```

You will have to `import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet`.